# in c++ program after pressing enter , "cin" will feed all Variables

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a program that takes two numbers and shows them on the screen.

However, when I hit "enter" after I input the first number, my program shows the answers before letting me input the second number.

Why does this happen?

```
int main()
{
    int n1;
    float n2;

    cin>>n1;

    cin>>n2;

    cout<<"int n:"<<n1<<endl<<"float n:"<<n2;

    return 0;
}
```

*I wanna input 0.25 and 35 but when I write 0.25 and hit enter suddenly shows the answer "int: n:0 float n:0.25" it doesn't let me write second num. my os is Win10 and this program compiled with DevCpp*

It works when both variables are ints.

Comment: What is the input that program fails on? What is the expected output and what is actual output?

Comment: What OS?  This works for me copied and slightly edited using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what input you are providing.

Comment: I wanna input 0.25 and 35 but when I write 0.25 and hit enter suddenly shows the answer "int: n:0 float n:0.25" it doesn't let me write second num. my os is Win10 and this program compiled with DevCpp

Comment: "0.25" would be parsed as "0" and  ".25", that expected and documented stream behaviour. When you have both ints, you cannot get second value at all in this case, it always will be 0, because cin locks up in bad state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `cin>>n1; cin>>n2;` and `cin >> n1 >>n2`. Enter key only serves as signal to sychronize input buffer and stream buffer. cin doesn't input per line,  it parses buffer when there is available volume of data. If parse incomplete, it waits. If parse can't be done, it stops and state bit changes. To continue parsing you have either ignore or clear part or whole buffer content.

Something wrong was entered in first line, causing `cin` to go into `bad()` state. Edge case might happen if you're running program through a remote terminal, some incorrect character could slip in, e.g. ^M  generated by new line from Windows would break `cin` stream on Linux. That's also case if you input from a file which was saved on different platform. On Windows line ends consist of two characters, #10 and #13. On linux steams expect only #13 as a new line and buffer flush signal, #10 is an unexpected character.

***Edit (after OP gave information about input data):***

"0.25" would be parsed as "0" and ".25", that expected and documented stream behavior. Parsing for `n1` had stopped as soon as stream encountered character which doesn't fit int pattern, which could be space, end of line, alphabetic or punctuation. Period considered a punctuation in this case

Then it tries to get a float from stream input and buffer contains ".25". It's a legal float notation and it gets assigned to `n2`.

When you have both "int", you cannot get second value at all with same input, it always will be 0, because `cin` locks up in bad state, i.e. method its `istream::good()` returns `false`. You have to check state of stream after reading variables. Any further formatted reading that wouldn't be able to parse `.25` wouldn't advance stream past that point.

If you want to read from stream exclusively line by line, you have to use `istream::getline()` method to get the string. There is also method `get` which can acquire content of stream and `ignore` which allows to discard part of stream.

Comment: I wanna input a float number for int variable and a float number for float variable but after write first num it shows the answers. ex) 12.5 then enter -> int n:12 float:0.5 why this happen? it doesn't let me write second num!!

Comment: @DariushStony. 12.5 is not integer. 12 is. Coincedental;y .5 is legal float. Parsing stops at period because period is an illegal character for int. Buffer stays preserved. Then .5 is parsed as float. Enter doesn't matter at all, it just flushes buffer, it doesn't separate values.

Comment: "I wanna input a float number for int variable" - What do you want the resulting value to be?